# How to add a Model (not an app) to django?

Tags: python, django, model, admin

I am using django 1.3 and just trying to add a simple model(not an app) to the admin site.
so i have tried:

```
from django.db import models

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    notes = models.TextField(db_name="Notes", max_length=15)

    def _str_(self):
        return self.notes

    class Admin:
        pass
```

and have also tried creating the admin.py file in the site root and in the /static/admin/ directory and have attempted two standard entries for it as follows:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mock.models import UserProfile                                       

admin.site.register(UserProfile)
```

and

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mock.models import UserProfile

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):                                               
    pass                                                                                

admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Why not just have an app? If it's profiles you're after take a look at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-profiles

Comment: Some off topic recomendation: in Django you have to overload the `__unicode__` method, not the `__str__` method. I will also strongly suggest you to read the complete [Django starting tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/) (part 2 is all about the **Django Admin**)

Comment: @mongoose_za thank you for the profile pkg info.

Comment: @julio.alegria I did read up on the part 2 and did forget about that part; although I did install apps that ran without, i do understand that the more I create, it will probably be needed later. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't define your `Admin` class in the model itself like below. That's the **really** old way to do it, from before Django 1.0. I'm not sure what tutorial or documentation you are using, but it's very out of date.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    notes = models.TextField(db_name="Notes", max_length=15)
    # don't do this!
    class Admin:
        pass
```

Defining a `UserProfileAdmin` is the correct approach. The admin.py file should not go in the `/static/admin/`. The static directory is for static files like CSS stylesheets and javascript files, not for Django code.

As for your question of whether you can define a model without defining an app, it's not a really good idea. Lots of parts of django assume that each model belongs to an app. For example the database table name is `appname_modelname`.

Creating an app doesn't take too long. Run the startapp command and it will create the base directory and files.

```
./manage.py startapp <appname>
```

All you then need to do is add the new app to `INSTALLED_APPS`, and create your `admin.py` file.

As your project gets bigger, keeping models in apps will keep it more organized. Many Django users create an app named `utils` (or similar) for the odd model.

Comment: Haven't seen `class Admin` in years!

Comment: @Yuji Tomita, ah yes, I did try django when it first came out and do remember seeing that syntax, so it did look correct to me... but Alasdair is correct, I should be mixing them in the actual models.

Comment: @ChrisHarty, you mean you shouldn't be. Not that it would do anything :)

Comment: @YujiTomita, yep, meant to say "shouldn't be".  It was a bit late when I replied :) . Ya, I am not sure about the end result for that, but I am not going to loose any more sleep over it going down that path.  Thank you for the correction :)

Comment: Wow, looks like my response and code to Alasdair's answer was taken out.  Wonder Why?? :(

Comment: @ChrisHarty - you can see why users rejected your edit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/189773) -- I don't think I agree with their decision, but it might have been better to add it as an answer rather than editing the question.